# About rand() in c

Tags: c, random

q1)

Is this implementation of rand() and srand():

- correct?
- used by the most popular implementations?
- required by the standard?

```
unsigned int __seed;

void srand(unsigned int s) {
    __seed = s;
}

int rand() {
    __seed = __deterministic_and_fast_mathematical_expression_that_depend_only_of_seed(__seed); // Call it expr(), Declared somewhere
    return __seed;
}
```

q2)

Then, if q1) is true (or in another way), is it true to say that there is cycles in such function, that rand() can be interpreted as a cyclic sequence given at a random point?

```
// Hypotetically
srand(a)
if rand() = b then expr(a) = b
if rand() = a then expr(b) = a
// Then any call to rand would give successively [a, b, a, b, a, ...] infinitely
// This example is for two values but can work for a sequence of any length
```

I assume that the rand() function is cyclic after a maximal of 2^64 iterations on 64 bits and 2^32 on 32 bits.
For example, if somewhere in the sequence there is:

```
12891, 872821, 33, 872821, 33, 872821, ... Infinitely
```

We can isolate the part `33, 872821` and the part before and make a arrow from second to first. Then the rand function could be described by this graph, generated by this procedure:

```
for(int i = 0; i < RAND_MAX; i++) {
    srand(i);
    while(rand() != i);
    // ISolate the cycle for seed = i
}
```

q3)

If q2) is true (or in another way), how can we ensure that this function won't give any "broken" sequence with repetitions or very fewly, or just it's unspecified?

q4)

Can we find out which seed come before a sequence?

Comment: That would depend on the __deterministic_and_fast_mathematical_expression_that_depend_only_of_seed wouldn't it?

Comment: Who says `rand()` has 64 bits of pseudo-randomness? The standard sure doesn't. Some systems have as little as 15 bits which is why `rand()` can't be trusted for just about anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> q1) Is this implementation of rand() and srand(): correct?

I would say no.
* Code does not certainly restrict the range of `rand()` to `[0...INT_MAX]`.   [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646124/about-rand-in-c/58651485#comment103598052_58646276).   `return __seed & INT_MAX` would solve that.
* Unreserved identifier `__seed` is a no-no.  C17dr 7.1.3 1. I'd expect `static unsigned __seed` to limit scope.
* For a user made `rand(),srand()`, I'd expect a `RAND_MAX` definition too.

> q1) Is this implementation of rand() and srand(): used by the most popular implementations?

Doubtful.  IAC, "most popular" implementations is subjective.  Billions of embedded processors per year are made and their popularity and smallish footprint may skew the idea of "most popular" implementation.  I see no advantage assuming such an implementation other than to exploit weak `rand()`.  I'd expect most implementations will tend toward using a state wider than the seed.<sup>**</sup>

> q1) Is this implementation of rand() and srand(): required by the standard?

No.  The standard is fairly open.

---

<sup>**</sup>Although the seed value is limited to an `unsigned`, say 32-bit, the state variable could be much wider -  perhaps hundreds of bits.  Of course this means that all states can not be seed points.

The `srand()` seed also may be mostly ignored.  As I read the spec, there is no requirement to use all the bits of the seed.

The quality of `srand(), rand()` could be great or weak - as small a range as `[0...32767]` and perhaps a cycle that small too.

> q4) Can we find out which seed come before a sequence?

Brute force comes to mind - try lots of seeds.  The same seed point will, by spec, generate the same `rand()` output sequence for *that* implementation.  Other than that, no specified way. Note, the desired seed may not exist to achieve a select sequence `rand()` from a seed.

Answer (score 2):

1) correct? yes
required? there is no specific requirement. the quality of the numbers generated is a "quality of implementation" issue

2) there are no requirements in the standard, except for repeatability

3) quality of implementation

4) quality of implementation

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Unix specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/rand.html) (and the [C standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html)), `rand()` will generate a sequence of pseudo-random numbers with a period of at least 2^32.

> The rand() function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to {RAND_MAX}  with a period of at least 2^32.

This means it will not repeat the same sequence of numbers until it reaches 2^32 numbers generated. As for your first question, it is deterministic as the same seed given to `rand()` will produce the exact same sequence every time.

Comment: Also needs to take account of `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: As the question is tagged with C and not with Unix, answers should apply the C standard and not the Unix standard.

Comment: The C standard linked to in this answer does not impose any period for the `rand()` function, the 2^32 requirement is in a "XSI" clause.